# How to setup i18n in an angular library?

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-library

I have a private angular library, where our team keeps components that are reused across our projects. We have the `@angular/localize` package installed in the projects, so the library has to use it too.

How do I expose the library translations to the user? How do I set up Angular's internationalization in a way so that the library consumers could override those translations in case they need to?